# trying to solve a 2D finite element analysis FEA problem by hand

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve this problem:

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nis.png)

so far I could do some math to reach here:

Multiply equation (1) by a test function $v$ and integrate over the domain $\Omega$. Then, we apply integration by parts to get the weak form of the problem:

Find $u$ such that $u = 0$ on $\Gamma_1$ and

\begin{equation}
    \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx = \int_{\Omega} 2v \, dx + \int_{\Gamma_2} v \, dS, \quad  \text{ with } v = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma_1.
\end{equation}

The bilinear form $a(u, v)$ and the linear functional $F(v)$ are:

\begin{align*}
    a(u, v) &= \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx, \\
    F(v) &= \int_{\Omega} 2v \, dx + \int_{\Gamma_2} v \, dS.
\end{align*}

My question is what exactly should i do next and how to proceed? What should be v? how to impliment it in the mesh? how to calculate the gradients etc and finally get to the solution u? Can someone help me step by step? Thanks.

Comment: You need a solution space and a test function space in order to continue. Normally you use some a piecewise polynomial basis with some maximum degree, for example a piecewise linear function supported on just one of the triangles. Once you've identified a solution space and a test function space of the same dimension, and the test functions are linearly independent, you pick a basis of each and then you get a matrix equation for the coefficients of your approximate solution.

Comment: can you be a bit more detailed than this? Like suggest some explicit test functions with some reasons and show how to impliment it in a couple of triangular elements at least?

Comment: The Laplacian is -2, not the gradient. (The gradient is a vector, and not a constant one.)

Comment: The problem is made very cryptic and unnecessarily complicated. This is what I start with: $\Gamma_2$ is the left side vertical frontier along y-axis, where the directional derivative of u(x,y) normal to frontier is 1; the remaining frontier is $\Gamma_1$ where u(x,y)=0; inside, $\Delta u=-2$.